# Event handling confusion in java

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I googled a lot of things about Event Handling and ended up more confused.
My question is simple:

```
Handler hand = new Handler();
aButton.addActionListener(hand);
private class Handler implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
//event handling code
}
}
```

Here, the button has registered the Action Listener for itself and it has passed the *hand* to actionPerformed (?) , how did the *hand* reached the actionPerformed function when the function names are not same ? Why did it even need to send the *hand* ?
Why did we even need to implement the interface when the methods inside the interface contains no code ?
Thank you

Comment: *it has passed the hand to actionPerformed (?)*: no. Not at all. You passed `hand` to `addActionListener()`. The button keeps a reference to `hand`, and calls its actionPerformed() method whenever it's clicked. Just like, if you give your address email to some web site, the web site can email you when it needs to notify you of some event. Why do you name your variable `hand`? It's not a hand. It's a handler.

Answer (score 1):

> Here, the button has registered the Action Listener for itself and it has passed the hand to actionPerformed (?)

No, `hand` is a reference to a `Handler` instance. `Handler` is a class that implements the `ActionListener` interface.

`aButton.addActionListener(hand)` registers the `Handler` instance references by `hand` as the action listener to be called when the button is clicked.

When the button is clicked, the `actionPerformed` method of that `Handler` instance will be executed.

> Why did we even need to implement the interface when the methods inside the interface contains no code ?

This is just an example. You are supposed to add code inside `actionPerformed` (to replace the `//event handling code` comment). Otherwise there is no need to register that `Handler` instance, since it does nothing.